# How to send payment info to paypal?

Tags: django, paypal, payment, credit-card

I'm currently using django-paypal (this may not be related to django at all) to get paypal payments, but the problem is I also need to store the cc info in the database itself.

Is there a way that I can get that info from paypal or have the user input that info in my site and then forward it to paypal to process the payment?

Comment: You almost certainly don't *need* to store cc info to your database. Doing so will mean you need to invest heavily into PCI-DSS compliance. You're probably looking to solve a different issue, such as reusing card details for multiple payments. Repost the actual issue you're trying to solve. (or better yet - search for it. There have been multiple q&a's on this site regarding these issues)

Comment: There isn't a way to grab credit card details from PayPal.

If you use Direct Payment buyers would enter their credit card information on your site and you can grab it that way.

Comment: @PayPal_Patrick. ...but you would discourage that, right? I presume PayPal would be aware of the PCI implications of what the questioner is asking?

Comment: If you're going to use Direct Payment you are required to be PCI compliant. There are rules for what kind of information you can store and how.